# Fragment and Service are working with same resources

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service

I'm making android app in which user can work with small images.

App has a backend (parse.com) where images located, so I can add and delete some images.
On the client side images store on SD (files) and there is sqlite table where filepaths located.

App has a Fragment that takes all available images and shows them in GridView with ImageViews. I'm using SQLiteCursorLoader/CursorAdapter to get filepaths and then just load bitmaps to ImageViews.
Also I have IntentService, that sync images with backend by timer. Its load and save to SD new images and remove files of images, that were deleted. Its also modify sqlite table with filepaths of images.

The problem is: IntentService can start doing his job in the same time when user works with Fragment. User can choose image, that has been already deleted by IntentService.

Is there any possibility for IntentService to check that Fragment (or other data consumers) working right now? Should IntentService stop doing his job in that case? 
Are there a 'good practices' of solving this kind of issues?

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: Have some state machine and check if the state is final then do your job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way to keep your UI up to date with your database is to implement the content obversable pattern using a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and observe the changes using the [Loader Manager](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

Your fragment will look something like this:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment 
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private CursorAdapter mAdapter;
    // ...
    @Override public void onViewCreated(View view) {
        // ...
        mAdapter = new ResourceCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.my_layout, null, false);
        // attach adapter to your grid-view...

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), MY_IMAGE_MODEL_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        // this automatically reloads your adapter and updates your grid-view
        mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor); 
    }

    @Override public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Note that the Uri that is passed to the `CursorLoader` will be observed for changes. When a change is detected, the Loader will query the specified Uri after which `onLoadFinished` is called. But it can only detect changes if you notify the system that a change took place on that Uri. You typically do that inside your content provider, after you have done an update, insert or delete. But it could also be done by your `IntentService` after it has deleted, inserted or updated your data.

The code to do that will look something like this:

```
getContentResolver().notifyChange(MY_IMAGE_MODEL_URI, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

in fragment class  Create a public static variable like

```
public static boolean active = false;
```

and oAcivityCreated method make it true

onpause or onStop make it false

you can this variable from IntentService

example

```
 if (myfragment.active){
  //do Somthing if fragment is running
  }else{
  //Somthing if  not running
  }
```

ithink it will work for you